# How is getElementById() implemented in machine code and why is not part of a DOM element when it is a part of a DOM document?

Tags: javascript, dom

Why isn't `getElementById()` part of a DOM element when at the same time it is a part of a DOM document, keeping in mind that document stands higher in a hierarchy than an element. How exactly is getElementById() implemented in machine code of browsers?

[image]?

Comment: From [the DOM spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nonelementparentnode) "Web compatibility prevents the getElementById() method from being exposed on elements ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` values **must** be unique in the document, so there's very little need to look for an element by id *within* another element. Just look for it on the document.

In the **rare** case you need to look for an element by `id` only within another element's descendants, you can use `querySelector` with an ID selector:

```
const e = someElement.querySelector("#the-id");
```

...but again, it's a rare use case that likely suggests that `id`s are being misused.

Comment: How exactly is getElementById() implemented in machine code of browsers?

Comment: @SmilingMouse - That will vary by browser. But however it's implemented, it's very, very fast.